# Is there a way of running a callback when the first winform is displayed?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there some callback I can hook into that is called when the first window of an application is made visible, whatever it is? This callback has to be registered before any message loop or anything like that is created, and I can't alter any existing calls to `Application.Run` or similar (I'm adding it in a postprocessing step, similar to postsharp)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how do you mean to attach any event without editing program.cs which is run first, but:

- run thread as soon as application starts
- in the thread, find a way to enumerate all windows that belong to the process
- if you have more then one window, fire your event, and discontinue running the thread.

Some info on how to iterate windows is [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/235120-urgent-how-iterate-all-windows-belonging-particular-process-c).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? Just add your code to the Main method which creates the first form?

Search for [Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) in your winform project.

Comment: I can't alter the existing calls to `Application.Run`. If I could I wouldn't be asking here! :)